# sys/ustat.h file not found

Tags: glibc, clang

I'm trying to build a modified version of the LLVM compiler as used in the [Pepper-project](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin)

I'm using [this](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin/blob/master/install_buffet.sh) script to install it, however it fails with this error:

```
/pequin/compiler/buffetfsm/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:132:10:
fatal error: 'sys/ustat.h' file not found
#include <sys/ustat.h>
```

It seems that `ustat.h` was removed in a newer glibc version, which makes sense as I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10. Everything worked fine on 18.04.

First idea is to downgrade to 18.04 again, but been reading up on that and most seem to not recommend it. Same with downgrading glibc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Downgrade will be the best solution as it 18.04 LTS is supported until 2023.

Comment: Will downgrading Ubuntu replace the glibc installation with an older version which contains ustat.h?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The 18.04 LTS releases contains needed file in [`libc6-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libc6-dev/filelist).

The main advantage would LTS status - the distro will be supported until 2023.